# Converting a SQL update statement to a View statement

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have an update statement formula for a table and the statement works, but i want to update my table automatically every time i add new data so i thought i should use a View instead.

This is my update statement:

```
followers f left outer join
       followers f2
       on f2.id = f.id
    set f.Growth = f.Growth_Speed/(SELECT AVG(f.Growth_Speed) FROM (SELECT f.Growth_Speed from followers f WHERE f.id <= f.id+1));
```

And here is my View statement:

```
CREATE VIEW `followers_view` AS
    select 
        `followers`.`id` AS `id`,
        `followers`.`date` AS `date`,
        `followers`.Growth_Speed` AS `Growth_Speed`
    From `my_database.followers`;
```

I would like to add that update statement as a fourth column in the View but not sure how to go about doing this.

Thanks

Comment: What IDE are u using?, have you heard about triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a [Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) to the table where you want to make the update when you insert new data

The code would be something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_table AFTER INSERT ON followers
        FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
              followers f left outer join followers f2   on f2.id = f.id
              set f.Growth = f.Growth_Speed/(SELECT AVG(f.Growth_Speed) FROM (SELECTf.Growth_Speed from followers f WHERE f.id <= f.id+1));            

            END
```

I guess followers is the table where  you insert the data, and the one where you want to update.

Comment: Similar to altering a View, how do we check the formula of the trigger or edit it in the future if needed?

Comment: There's no way to [alter a Trigger](http://mysqlresources.com/documentation/stored-routines/alter-trigger), so you'll have to drop it and create it again.

Comment: @jenn Also if you still want to use a View to update your data you should check [this information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html), be careful 'couse there are some conditions and restrictions to do it with a View, i recommend you to use a Trigger

Comment: This trigger didnt work, probably need to edit the syntax but thanks for introducing me to triggers.